# Commas and articles in dissertation title

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, commas

Given these options, what is the correct title for a PhD dissertation:

1. **Efficient Parallelizable** Algorithm for Redundant Manipulators
2. **An Efficient Parallelizable** Algorithm for Redundant Manipulators
3. **Efficient, Parallelizable** Algorithm for Redundant Manipulators
4. **An Efficient, Parallelizable** Algorithm for Redundant Manipulators

[This article](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1149/2.086311jes/meta) suggests the answer is number 2., but I can't find any reliable source on that matter. On the other hand, [here](https://readingcraze.com/index.php/choosing-title-research-paper/) we can read that:

> You can have a colon or a comma in between the title phrase where required

Comment: The page at readingcraze.com is very poorly written, and I suspect that whoever wrote it was not a native speaker of English. ("in between the title phrase" doesn't even make sense; something can only be *in between* two or more things, not one thing!)  I would not use it as a resource.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a strong preference: [Efficient parallelizable](https://dspace.rpi.edu/handle/20.500.13015/1872), [A hybrid parallelizable](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/IMECE/proceedings-abstract/IMECE2006/47675/451/322255), [A simple, efficient, parallelizable](https://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2100/paper3.pdf)... I'd recommend asking your supervisor, although there may be some style guide you can consult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a researcher with a Ph.D. in computer science, I offer my sense of what is appropriate and accepted style in the field. While the determiner *an* is not mandatory, I highly recommend it (see Lambie’s point above).

As to the comma, whether to use it hinges on a perhaps subtle matter. If the author intends to highlight that the algorithm is both efficient and parallelizable, then the comma is called for. But if instead the author is working in the context of parallelizable algorithms and wishes to describe their own contribution as introducing one that is efficient , then there should be no comma.

Comment: Great point! I recently stumbled upon this short bit [1], and I got the same impression as you said here :)
[1] https://www.grammarflip.com/curriculum/commas-between-two-adjectives

Answer (score 1):

An Efficient Parallelizable 3D Thermoelectrochemical Model of a Li-Ion Cell,

The authors are native speakers and that title is correct.

Also, it shows *a bit of scientific humility*.

They are presenting "a model of a something", which shows cognizance of what might be a non-definitive model.

Titles are not written like journalistic headlinese.

The book, "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy" has no humility at all. Douglas Adams has a title that implies that there is only this one. [I am using a joke to illustrate my point.]

Answer (score 0):

In "regular" English, the noun "algorithm" would require a determiner. However, titles of research papers often use "[headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese)", so the indefinite article is optional. I'd recommend keeping it unless you really need to shorten the title.

Because the adjectives "efficient" and "parallelizable" seem to be in series (i.e., both seem to modify "algorithm" equally), there should be a comma between them.